# Curly Brace tikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

Im trying to force Latex to do a \newline on the text of my curly brace, or it doesn't allow me and the result is the following:
[image]

As you see, there are some curly braces very close, so the texts overlap. I'd like to force a \newline, but it doesn't allow me! =(

A code of one of my curly braces:

```
 %Brace
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}] let \p1=(pVI11.north), \p2=(pVI11.south) in
($(-9.8, \y1+1.5em)$) -- ($(-9.8, \y2-1em)$) 
node[at start, left=10pt, rotate=90] {Creation fichier \newline shape.tex};
```

Thanks 4 ur help! ^^ (and sorry 4 my english... ^^ )!Bye!Gemma

Comment: Use `align=center` and instead of `\newline` you canuse double backslash `\\\`